# Python numpy: column arrays (2d) or lists (1d)

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, is it recommended to create column arrays (2d arrays) rather than 1d arrays? For example, whereas `Z = np.zeros((12,))` defines a 1-dimensional list, it might also be preferable to form `Z = np.zeros((12,1))`.

Comment: Use the 1-d array by default.  Only use the 2-d shape when you *know* you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the use case. Both possibilities exist for a reason: if `Z` can be a matrix but just happens to have one column, make it a column vector. If `Z` is always a single vector, make it 1-d unless some operation (or library) requires the other format; 1-d is usually a bit easier to work with.